# Nested completion block not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I've got a nested completion block set to initialize an `SKProduct`. If I put a breakpoint right before the completion block, the inside block executes OK (I can poll for `_product`) but the completion block never fires.

If I call `completion()` immediately within this block it executes, but not if I call it within the completion block of the nested block.

```
- (void)initializeProduct:(NSString*)bundleId completion:(void(^)(BOOL finished, NSError* error))completion
{
    // completion(YES, nil); If I call completion here, it executes
    NSSet* dataSet;
    dataSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:@[bundleId]];
    [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.production = NO;

    if(![IAPShare sharedHelper].iap) {
        NSSet* dataSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:bundleId, nil];
        [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap = [[IAPHelper alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:dataSet];
        [IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products = @[bundleId];
    }

    [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap requestProductsWithCompletion:^(SKProductsRequest* request,SKProductsResponse* response)
     {
         if(response > 0 ) {
             _product = [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products objectAtIndex:0]; // We get this far
             // ^ breakpoint on this line shows _product is now an SKProduct 
             completion(YES, nil); // but this never fires
         }
         else
         {
             completion(YES, error);
                           // ^ yes, error is defined in my code, I'm being lazy
         }
     }];
}
```

I'm calling it in a method like this with another completion block (and it never enters the block):

```
- (void)priceForBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId completion:(void(^)(NSString* price))completion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NO), ^{
        [self initializeProduct:bundleId completion:^(BOOL finished, NSError *error) {
            // Breakpoint placed here never catches
            if (!error)
            {
                NSString* price = [RSStore priceAsStringForLocale:_product.priceLocale price:_product.price];
                [defaults setValue:price forKey:@"bigBoxPrice"];
                completion(price);
            }
            else
            {
                completion(nil);
            }

        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like a threading problem. You're doing everything on a background thread, so who knows when the pieces execute? I don't know what IAPShare is, but how do you know it's thread-safe?

Comment: IAPShare is definitely thread safe, but good point about me calling it on the background thread. Lemme try it on the main thread.

Comment: Nope, no dice. Also note the fact that the IAPShare callback does fire (it sets `_product`), it's the parent one that doesn't. Unfortunately removing the GCD wrapper didn't help.

Comment: Does your completion block *exist* at the point where it's being invoked? ARC may be ditching it before that point because it can't correctly reason about the block's lifespan given how you're using it.

Comment: Well, I don't quite understand what you mean by "doesn't fire". You've got a debugger. You've got a breakpoint. When the call to the innermost `completion()` comes along, dive into it and see where you go.

Comment: It doesn't execute the callback in the parent block. My guess here, based on stepping through, is that it is trying to call its own completion block and ends up in a loop, seeing as it never seems to end.

Comment: There is no need to guess. Stepping tells you what _actually_ happens. What happens?

Comment: It loops over and over. So I can only assume it's calling itself.

Comment: It is certainly true that you use the word `completion` a lot. Did you know that you are allowed to change the name of the parameters here? That might straighten things out.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware ;) No, giving each a unique name doesn't help.

Comment: :) Well it would sure help me. I find the code incomprehensible as it stands. Of course that could just be me...

Comment: Admittedly I had originally created them as independent methods, now I'm being silly and calling one from the other. Renaming was a distant thought until I actually got it working.